# How to feed training data into libSVM in c#?

Tags: c#, svm, libsvm

I'm currently working on libsvm and I want to make a svm classifier on a data set, let me explain :

for example I have a data file like that

good 0.1 2.5 10 11 1.24 .

bad 10 11.3 23.2 7.4 4.2 .

verygood 10 11 33.2 2.4 3 .

... 
...
etc.

-- when good, bad, verygood are class labels and the others are values for the attributes for each one.

and then I want to classify an input from the user like that :

0.2 11 3.2 11.2 6.4

I want to know how to classify that input using libsvm how can I code it easily or how I can use the classes in the lib,

I'm currently working on c# version of libsvm,
if anyone can explain how I can use it clearly even if in java and I can understand and convert it into a c# version.

HINT : I don't want how I can input the data to the library, I want to code my own code using the libsvm.

thanks.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer ?

Comment: solved from 2 years :) ..

Comment: good, please post the answer your self and accept. It might help others in future